# Create pip package. Error when installing

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I can't figure error when installing my own package.

I'm creating package from:

```
Mapp/
   CHANGES.txt
   LICENSE.txt
   MANIFEST.in
   README.txt
   setup.py
   mapp/
      __init__.py
      core/
          __init__.py
          ...
      utils/
          __init__.py
          ...
```

Then I run:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

The output is:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
creating Mapp-0.1.0 (and lots of creatin) ...
making hard links in Mapp-0.1.0...
'' not a regular file -- skipping
hard linking CHANGES.txt -> Mapp-0.1.0 (and lots of linking) ...
Writing Mapp-0.1.0/setup.cfg
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'Mapp-0.1.0' (and everything under it)
```

Then I will execute:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

and output is:

```
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing Mapp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Mapp.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Mapp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'Mapp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/mapp
copying mapp/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/mapp (and lots of copying)
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mapp/dataset/files.py to files.pyc (and lots of compiling)
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
installing scripts to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO/scripts
running install_scripts
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.7
error: file '/home/user/workspace/Mapp' does not exist
```

But wierd is that /home/user/workspace/Mapp exists but it is FOLDER not FILE.

Please I'm trying solve this very day and now I don't know what to do. Thank you.

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='Mapp',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='Ondrej Pelikan',
    author_email='onpelikan@gmail.com',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
    scripts=[''],
    url='http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Mapp/',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Package for simplify MAPP prediction analysis workflow.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Lesser General Public License v3 (LGPLv3)',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],
)
```

**MANIFEST.IN**

```
include *.txt
recursive-include mapp *.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! Problem causes:

```
scripts=[''],
```

There can't be empty list. This line have to be deleted! And then it works!